# Android NFC connection issue with Glucose device which has NFC feature

Tags: android, nfc

I am new to Android NFC Development. I have one Glucose device which has NFC feature.

The issue is when I am trying to connect my device using NFC, I am following below steps:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
    String searchedTech = NfcV.class.getName();
    for (String tech : techList) {
        if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
             try 
             {
                 NfcV nfcvTag = NfcV.get(myTag);
                 nfcvTag.close();
                 nfcvTag.connect();
             }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                //Used for DEBUG : Log.i("Exception","Get System Info Exception " + e.getMessage());`enter code here`
             }
        }
      }      
   }
}
```

I have already wrote request permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

I am getting IOException with no detailed message and I am stuck here.

Does anyone know what may be the issue here?

Am I missing something to write?